# Find the bijective function to prove countability

Tags: abstract-algebra

Give a bijective function which shows that Z is numerically equivalent to mZ + b for any real numbers m and b.

I'm thinking of f(x)= ax +b but is this too simple? Thanks

Comment: Presumably $m\neq 0$.

Comment: A linear equation is fine. Define $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \ ;\ f:x\mapsto mx+b.$
Then show $f$ is both injective and surjective, and you're done.